# Core Data many to many relation with intermediate table (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**TL;DR EDIT with answer**

As Wain perfectly answered this is how I get my information now:

```
let ingredientsToRecipe = recipe.valueForKey("ingredientsToRecipe")! as! NSSet
for i in ingredientsToRecipe {
  print(i.valueForKey("amount")!)
  print(i.valueForKeyPath("ingredient.name")!)
}
```

**Original question**

I have a huge problem understanding the usage of intermediate tables in CoreData. I've searched SO for answers and found a few threads about intermediate tables and many-to-many relations but those where either Objective-C or didn't help me.

I have the following setup (simplified):
[image]

Now I want to add a new recipe with a bunch of ingredients.
Let's say a Burger. The burger consists of

- 1 cocumber,
- 1 Tomato,
- 1 Meat,
- 2 bread

  (yummy...)

This is what I tried so far:

```
// Core Data
let appDelegate =
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Recipe",
                                                inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
// creating a new recipe with name and id
let recipe = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
recipe.setValue("Burger", forKey: "name")
recipe.setValue("B_001", forKey: "id")
```

Now I got an `Array:[NSManagedObject]` of of ingredients (created just like the Burger) and a `Dictionary` of amounts to the ingredient_IDs. This is how I'm trying to marry my Recipe with the ingredients (over the intermediate table).

```
for i in selectedIngredients { // the ingredient array
  let ingredientsToRecipe =     NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("RecipeIngredient", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
  
  ingredientsToRecipe.setValue(i, forKey: "ingredient")
  ingredientsToRecipe.setValue(recipe, forKey: "recipe")

  let quantity = Double(quantityDictionary[(i.valueForKey("id") as! String)]!) // the amount-to-ID dictionary
  ingredientsToRecipe.setValue("\(quantity)", forKey: "quantity")
}
```

In the end I simply save everything:

```
do {
  try managedContext.save()
  print("Saved successfully")
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} catch let error as NSError  {
  print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

All this above somehow works. But now I'm struggling to fetch information about my recipes.
How am I supposed to fetch the amount of tomatoes of this specific burger?

Things like
`recipe.valueForKey("RecipeIngredient").valueForKey("amount")` work but I don't know which amount is from which ingredient.
Am I doing anything wrong?
What can/should I do better?

The goal is to create a recipe with ingredients and later populate a Table with information about the recipe and the amounts of it's ingredients (and the ingredients themselves).

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power of the intermediate object is that it takes your many-to-many relationship and breaks it into multiple one-to-many relationships. The to-one relationships are easy to navigate.

So, from your `Recipe` you can get an array of `RecipeIngredients`, and for each one you can get `valueForKey("amount")` and `valueForKeyPath("ingredient.name")`.

Comment: Omg thank you. I had such a block in my head. Works like a charm this way. Can not upvote twice though but please feel the hug!

Answer (score 1):

For you to get the amount of an ingredient for a specific recipe you can create a fetch request at RecipeIngredient using predicates like this :

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RecipeIngredient")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipe.name = %@ AND ingredient.name = %@", "burger","tomato")
request.predicate = predicate
```

Then you simply get tha amount value from the returned RecipeIngredient entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! @Wain's response better fits my needs though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `valueForKey` and `valueForKeyPath` to access these kinds of properties... Rather, you should let Core Data do the work of traversing the relationships for you, and just ask for what you need using dot syntax:

```
for item in recipe.ingredientsToRecipe {
    print(item.amount)
    print(item.ingredient.name)
}
```

I suggest that you rename your intermediate entity from `IngredientsToRecipe` (which is thinking like database design) to `Items` or `ReceipeItems` to better capture what it is—the item that actually appears in a recipe, rather than the underlying food type itself.

But whether you do that or not, you could certainly name the relationship on Receipe to be `items`, resulting in the much more readable:

```
for item in recipe.items {
    print(item.amount)
    print(item.ingredient.name)
}
```

You could also go further and create a computed property on the intermediate entity called `name` that simply returned `ingredient.name`, which would then let you use:

```
for item in recipe.items {
    print(item.amount)
    print(item.name)
}
```

:)